# pager program like less, able to repeat top N lines

Tags: command-line, less, pager

Is there any way to make `less` program repeat first line (or first 2 lines) on every displayed page?

Is there any other pager program which can do this?

This would be a killer-app for database table browsing, think `mysql` or `psql` or `gqlplus`...

See the screenshot in the bottom of [this page](http://staging.enterprisedb.com/documentation/edbdev-viewdata.html). I want to repeat header line + horizontal ascii bar.

Comment: Oh boy, that asks for an extension to less, like a Freeze Pane point. For example --freeze-pane 10,2 would keep 1 line of column headers and 10 columns row header. Horizontal and vertical scrolling would preserve the row and column headers respectively. That would be really cool to use for a psql pager (merlinmoncure.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-psql-with-less.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a solution using Vim.

First, you need a Vim macro, which will do most of the work. Save it in `~/.vim/plugin/less.vim`:

```
" :Less
" turn vim into a pager for psql aligned results 
fun! Less()
  set nocompatible
  set nowrap
  set scrollopt=hor
  set scrollbind
  set number
  execute 'above split'
  " resize upper window to one line; two lines are not needed because vim adds separating line
  execute 'resize 1'
  " switch to lower window and scroll 2 lines down 
  wincmd j
  execute 'norm! 2^E'
  " hide statusline in lower window
  set laststatus=0
  " hide contents of upper statusline. editor note: do not remove trailing spaces in next line!
  set statusline=\  
  " arrows do scrolling instead of moving
  nmap ^[OC zL
  nmap ^[OB ^E
  nmap ^[OD zH
  nmap ^[OA ^Y
  nmap <Space> <PageDown>
  " faster quit (I tend to forget about the upper panel)
  nmap q :qa^M
  nmap Q :qa^M
endfun
command! -nargs=0 Less call Less()
```

Second, to emulate a pager, you need to invoke vim so that it will:

- read standard input
- but if argument is given on command line, read whatever comes there
- work in read-only mode
- skip all init scripts, but instead execute Less macro defined above

I put this together as helper script in `~/bin/vimpager`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
what=-
test "$@" && what="$@"
exec vim -u NONE -R -S ~/.vim/plugin/less.vim -c Less $what
```

Make the script executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/vimpager`.

Third, you need to override pager program for psql. Do not set variable `PAGER` globally, as it can affect other programs, not only psql. Instead, add this to your `~/.psqlrc` file:

```sh
\setenv PAGER ~/bin/vimpager
```

*Voila*! After reloading your profile, you can enjoy the result, which should behave as expected (arrow keys browse both vertically and horizontally) and look like this: [image: vimpager in action]. Plus, all the power of Vim is right there if you need it.

Comment: This is lovely, I tried it. Now it would be nice if one could add row headers also, instead of these row numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [SQL Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode) in Emacs/XEmacs?

It's certainly not as simple to use as `more` or `less`, but it does what your asking for, leaving a header row while scrolling results vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know Emacs but it sound interesting. I would eventually need a shell script which would: start emacs, run psql there, (with given conn. params), enable sql-mode and do what I want (always freeze top 2 rows when there are query results larger than screen size). any hints on that?

Answer (score 3):

This borrows very heavily from [the accepted answer,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27840/143088) but adds...

- Faster scrolling
- Cannot accidentally scroll into the header
- Syntax highlighting (some credit [belongs here](https://unencumberedbyfacts.com/2016/01/04/psql-vim-happy-face/))

  - Positive/negative numbers, dates, times, `NULL`, True/False (and T/F, Y/N, Yes/No)
  - Row numbers, if you have them before a pipe char.
- Help text
- Support for the Vim that is included with [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org)
- Do not threaten to update the view if the stdin buffer changes

Some portions may have to be tweaked for your specific output, since I do not use `psql`. I also have slightly different helper functions for my purposes, but they are similar to those in the [accepted answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27840/143088)

### Sample input

```
  | ID |   First   |     Last     | Member | Balance |
--+----+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
 1|  4 | Tom       | Hanks        | False  |    0.00 |
 2| 12 | Susan     | Patterson    | True   |   10.00 |
 3| 23 | Harriet   | Langford-Wat | False  |    0.00 |
 4|  8 | Jerry     |     NULL     | True   | -382.94 |
[… More rows …]
10| 87 | Horace    | Weaver       | False  |   47.52 |
```

### Code

```
" :HeadPager
" Turn vim into a pager with a header row
" Adapted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27840/143088
fun! HeadPager()
    " If you didn't get three lines, shortcut out
    if line('$') < 3
        set nocompatible
        nmap <silent> q :qa!<c-M>
        nmap <silent> Q :qa!<c-M>
        return
    endif

    set noswapfile
    set nocompatible
    set nowrap
    set scrollopt=hor
    set scrollbind

    " Hide statusline in lower window
    set laststatus=0
    " Explain mapped chars in status line.
    set statusline=\ \ \ Q\ to\ quit\.\ Arrows\ or\ mousewheel\ to\ scroll\.\ \(Vim\ commands\ work\,\ too\.\)

    " Delete/copy header lines
    silent execute '1,2d'

    " Split screen with new buffer (opens at top)
    execute 'new'

    " Switch to upper split
    wincmd k

    " Paste the header over the blank line
    execute 'norm! Vp'

    " Header highlighting
    syn match Pipe "|"
    hi def Pipe ctermfg=blue
    syn match Any /[^|]\+/
    hi def Any ctermfg=yellow

    " Switch back to lower split for scrolling
    wincmd j

    " Set lower split height to maximum
    execute "norm! \<c-W>_"

    " Syntax highlighting
    syn cluster CellContents contains=None
    syn match Pipe "|" contained nextgroup=@CellContents skipwhite
    hi def Pipe ctermfg=blue

    " Start with newline or |. End right before next | or EOL
    syn region Cell start=/\v(^|\|)\s*/ end=/\v(\||$)\@=/ contains=LineNumber,Pipe

    syn match NumPos /\v\+?\d+(,?\d{3})*\.?\d*\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    syn match NumNeg   /\v-\d+(,?\d{3})*\.?\d*\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    syn match NumZero         /\v[+-]?0+\.?0*\ze *(\||$)\@=/  contained
    hi def NumPos ctermfg=cyan
    hi def NumNeg ctermfg=red
    hi def NumZero ctermfg=NONE
    syn cluster CellContents add=NumPos,NumNeg,NumZero

    syn match DateVal /\v\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ contained nextgroup=TimeVal skipwhite
    syn match TimeVal /\v\d{1,2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?(\.\d+)?(Z| ?\c[AP]M)?\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    hi def DateVal ctermfg=magenta
    hi def TimeVal ctermfg=magenta
    syn cluster CellContents add=DateVal,TimeVal

    syn match TrueVal /\v\c(t(rue)?|y(es)?)\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    syn match FalseVal /\v\c(f(alse)?|no?)\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    hi def TrueVal ctermfg=green
    hi def FalseVal ctermfg=red
    syn match NullVal /\v\cnull?\ze *(\||$)\@=/ contained
    hi def NullVal ctermbg=gray ctermfg=black
    syn cluster CellContents add=TrueVal,FalseVal,NullVal

    syn match LineNumber /^ *\d\+/ contained
    hi def LineNumber ctermfg=yellow

    " Arrows do scrolling instead of moving
    nmap <silent> <Up> 3<c-Y>
    nmap <silent> <Down> 3<c-E>
    nmap <silent> <Left> zH
    nmap <silent> <Right> zL
    nmap <Space> <PageDown>
    " Faster quit (I tend to forget about the upper panel)
    nmap <silent> q :qa!<c-M>
    nmap <silent> Q :qa!<c-M>

    " Ignore external updates to the buffer
    autocmd! FileChangedShell */fd/*
    autocmd! FileChangedRO */fd/*
endfun
command! -nargs=0 HeadPager call HeadPager()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple 'regions' in `screen`:

```
$ cat screenrc.sql
escape ^aa  # adjust as needed
bind q quit # to quickly exit
screen 0 less ${FILE}
screen 1 less ${FILE}
split  # create two regions
focus top # starting with the top region
resize 4  # make it four lines (one for screen line, one for less prompt)
select 0  # display window 0
focus bottom  # in the bottom region
select 1  # display window 1 and focus here
```

Then you just need to set the $FILE environment variable:

```
$ FILE=$HOME/.bash_profile screen -mc screenrc.sql
```

Comment: this is almost what I wanted, but (a) the top window does not scroll right, so it is useless for wide tables

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'useless for wide tables'; screen can expand to the size of the terminal (if it doesn't run the `fit` screen command).  I had thought that you didn't want the top to scroll.  When I tested it on my own, both windows scroll as they should.  The top scrolls two lines (1-2, 3-4, 5-6, etc.) and the bottom scrolls as needed.  What is the behavior you are seeing/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a number before the 'forward' and it will scroll N lines, not a full length.  So if your terminal window is 40 lines, type `38f` to start scrolling only 38 lines, leaving the last 2 line from the last 'page.'  From the manpage:

```
   SPACE or ^V or f or ^F
          Scroll forward N  lines,  default  one  window  (see  option  -z
          below).   If  N  is  more  than  the screen size, only the final
          screenful is displayed.  Warning: some systems use ^V as a  spe‐
          cial literalization character.

   z      Like  SPACE,  but  if  N is specified, it becomes the new window
          size.

   b or ^B or ESC-v
          Scroll backward N lines,  default  one  window  (see  option  -z
          below).   If  N  is  more  than  the screen size, only the final
          screenful is displayed.
```

Comment: I need to keep _first_, not _last_ N lines. As "freeze top N rows" in Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't know if a utility that would do that.  Then what I suggest is: use `screen` or `tmux` to create two panes, resize of the first one to two lines (`resize 2`) and then run `less`, in the second pane, run `less` normally.  You could set this up as a script with a specific .screenrc file.  See alternate answer.